# Android result not working

Tags: java, android

I try to make an app which uses 3 EditTexts and 2 separate RadioGroups, one with Male/Female and one with 4 options. The result is not showing up and i think it's stuck at radio buttons finding the id's.

Java (CODE UPDATED):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultat);

    calcul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);

    greutate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
    String greutatecalcul = greutate.getText().toString();
    final double greutateDouble = Double.valueOf(greutatecalcul);

    inaltime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
    String inaltimecalcul = inaltime.getText().toString();
    final double inaltimeDouble = Double.valueOf(inaltimecalcul);

    varsta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    String varstacalcul = varsta.getText().toString();
    final double varstaDouble = Double.valueOf(varstacalcul);

    radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            int position2 = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            if (position2 == 0) {
                bmr = (66 + (13.75 * greutateDouble) + (5 * inaltimeDouble) * (6.76 * varstaDouble));

            } else if (position2 == 1) {
                bmr = (655 + (9.56 * greutateDouble) + (1.85 * inaltimeDouble) - (4.68 * varstaDouble));

            }
        }

    });


    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton2 = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton2);
            if (position == 0) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.25);
                stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);



            } else if (position == 1) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.35);
                stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);



            } else if (position == 2) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.55);
                stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);



            } else if (position == 3) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.75);

                stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);

            }
        }

    });
    calcul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {



            answer.setText(stringdouble);



        }

    });


}
```

}

And by testing on phone, in the Android Monitor i get

```
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

every time i press the calculate button.

I tried another method with onClick but i couldn't manage to make it work either, it was still stuck at those 2 Male/Female radio's.

Any ideas on how can i get past these? Thank you!

Comment: You mean when you press on answer you don't get result. am I right?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens. Just those 2 messages appear in the Android monitor.

Comment: the `OnClickListener` is set on TextView, and there are no `OnClickListener` on `Button`.

Comment: Ok, so i modified 

calcul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calcul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
and the same thing happens.

Comment: Ok, i updated the code. Now i get an error of emptyString and i guess the answer.setText is not returning anything. What else should i bring in the OnClickListener or is the variable stringdouble used incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code something like below with your logic

```
     public static double consum;
    public static double bmr;
    public EditText greutate;
    public EditText inaltime;
    public EditText varsta;
    public Button calcul;
    public TextView answer;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rezultat);

 greutate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
                String greutatecalcul = greutate.getText().toString();
                final double greutateDouble = Double.valueOf(greutatecalcul);

                inaltime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);
                String inaltimecalcul = inaltime.getText().toString();
                final double inaltimeDouble = Double.valueOf(inaltimecalcul);

                varsta=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
                String varstacalcul = varsta.getText().toString();
                final double varstaDouble = Double.valueOf(varstacalcul);

                calcul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
        radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int position2 = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                if (position2 == 0) {
                    bmr = (66 + (13.75 * greutateDouble) + (5 * inaltimeDouble) * (6.76 * varstaDouble));
                    String stringdouble2= Double.toString(bmr);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble2);
                }
                else if (position2 == 1) {
                    bmr = (655 + (9.56 * greutateDouble) + (1.85 * inaltimeDouble) - (4.68 * varstaDouble));
                    String stringdouble2= Double.toString(bmr);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble2);
                }
            }

        });


        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton2 = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton2);
                if (position == 0) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.25);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);



                } else if (position == 1) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.35);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);


                } else if (position == 2) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.55);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);


                } else if (position == 3) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.75);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);

                }
            }

        });

        answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
                RadioGroup radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);


                int radioButtonID = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton = radioGroup2.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int position2 = radioGroup2.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                if (position2 == 0) {
                    bmr = (66 + (13.75 * greutateDouble) + (5 * inaltimeDouble) * (6.76 * varstaDouble));
                    String stringdouble2= Double.toString(bmr);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble2);
                }
                else if (position2 == 1) {
                    bmr = (655 + (9.56 * greutateDouble) + (1.85 * inaltimeDouble) - (4.68 * varstaDouble));
                    String stringdouble2= Double.toString(bmr);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble2);
                }

                 radioButtonID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                View radioButton2 = radioGroup.findViewById(radioButtonID);
                int position = radioGroup.indexOfChild(radioButton2);
                if (position == 0) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.25);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);



                } else if (position == 1) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.35);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);


                } else if (position == 2) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.55);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);


                } else if (position == 3) {
                    consum = (bmr * 1.75);
                    String stringdouble= Double.toString(consum);
                    answer.setText(stringdouble);

                }




            }

        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double consum;
public static double bmr;
EditText greutate;
EditText inaltime;
EditText varsta;
Button calcul;
TextView answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rezultat);

    greutate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);

    inaltime=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.height);

    varsta=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);

    setUpAll();

}

private void setUpAll(){
    String greutatecalcul = greutate.getText().toString();
    final double greutateDouble = Double.valueOf(greutatecalcul);
    String inaltimecalcul = inaltime.getText().toString();
    final double inaltimeDouble = Double.valueOf(inaltimecalcul);
    String varstacalcul = varsta.getText().toString();
    final double varstaDouble = Double.valueOf(varstacalcul);
    radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            int position2 = group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
            if (position2 == 0) {
                bmr = (66 + (13.75 * greutateDouble) + (5 * inaltimeDouble) * (6.76 * varstaDouble));
                String stringdouble2 = Double.toString(bmr);
                answer.setText(stringdouble2);
            } else if (position2 == 1) {
                bmr = (655 + (9.56 * greutateDouble) + (1.85 * inaltimeDouble) - (4.68 * varstaDouble));
                String stringdouble2 = Double.toString(bmr);
                answer.setText(stringdouble2);
            }
        }
    });
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged (RadioGroup group,int checkedId){
            int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            View radioButton2 = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);
            int position = group.indexOfChild(radioButton2);
            if (position == 0) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.25);
                String stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);
                answer.setText(stringdouble);

            } else if (position == 1) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.35);
                String stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);
                answer.setText(stringdouble);
            } else if (position == 2) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.55);
                String stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);
                answer.setText(stringdouble);

            } else if (position == 3) {
                consum = (bmr * 1.75);
                String stringdouble = Double.toString(consum);
                answer.setText(stringdouble);
            }
       }
    });
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: Gives me a empty String error when starting the app.

Comment: first enter few things inside editText fields. the three strings u are extracting are from editText. they can't be empty. or put a check like:
`if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(string))`